# Termux code to install git on termux in Android mobile

Tags: git, termux

```
$ pkg install github
```

Says:

```
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package github
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to install `git` not `github`. Github.com is **a** git hosting, one of many (though one of the most famous).

From https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Development_Environments:

```
pkg up
pkg install git
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can install git in Termux by just typing**

```
pkg install git
```

**But if** you are facing **any error** then before installing git **you should run**

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

and this updates all the dependencies and you won't get any error.
If you wanna know more about termux then visit my site [www.learntermux.tech](https://www.learntermux.tech/)